# Cant find model data with parameters on rails controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called `BankList` and this model has two columns, `code` and `name`, so on `BankList` controller I'm trying to find this model by `code`, but the JSON always return empty like:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

***Controller***:

```
  class BanksListController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :null_session

  before_action :set_bank_list, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @banks_list = BankList.all

    render json: @banks_list
  end

  def show
    render json: @bank_list
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def set_bank_list
    @bank_list = BankList.where(code: params[:code])
  end

  def set_bank_list_params
    params(:bank_list).permit(:code, :name)
  end
end
```

***Routes:*** 
resources :banks_list

postman URL:

http://localhost:3007/banks_list/033

obs: the "033" would be a string

***thanks for the help!***

Comment: Please show your controller's code and routes. I guess that you need to use `params[:id]` instead of `params[:code]`

Comment: added controller and route into post, so on show method i would like to find by code, like find by code being  "033"

Comment: I am sure that for `update`, `show` and `destroy` you should use `BankList.find_by(code: params[:code])` because you need to get a single record from DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment you need to use `params[:id]` or change your route to `resources :banks_list, param: :code`. Because by default your routes look like this:

```
                     banks_list_index GET    /banks_list(.:format)                                                                    banks_list#index
                                      POST   /banks_list(.:format)                                                                    banks_list#create
                       new_banks_list GET    /banks_list/new(.:format)                                                                banks_list#new
                      edit_banks_list GET    /banks_list/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           banks_list#edit
                           banks_list GET    /banks_list/:id(.:format)                                                                banks_list#show
                                      PATCH  /banks_list/:id(.:format)                                                                banks_list#update
                                      PUT    /banks_list/:id(.:format)                                                                banks_list#update
                                      DELETE /banks_list/:id(.:format)                                                                banks_list#destroy
```

With `resources :banks_list, param: :code` they will look like this:

```
                     banks_list_index GET    /banks_list(.:format)                                                                    banks_list#index
                                      POST   /banks_list(.:format)                                                                    banks_list#create
                       new_banks_list GET    /banks_list/new(.:format)                                                                banks_list#new
                      edit_banks_list GET    /banks_list/:code/edit(.:format)                                                         banks_list#edit
                           banks_list GET    /banks_list/:code(.:format)                                                              banks_list#show
                                      PATCH  /banks_list/:code(.:format)                                                              banks_list#update
                                      PUT    /banks_list/:code(.:format)                                                              banks_list#update
                                      DELETE /banks_list/:code(.:format)                                                              banks_list#destroy
```

Comment: I'm happy to help :)